# Use an Async vb.net webservice with a javascript call

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asynchronous

I have a VB.Net web service that uses a HttpClient and is called using Javascript

```
            <WebMethod()>
Public Async Function ADMIN_SearchGrantsJSON_projectNumber_Async(projectNumber As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)
    Dim term As String = projectNumber.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim offset As Integer = 0
    Dim retLimit As Integer = 50
    Dim TotalCount As Integer = 0
    Dim termName As String = "projectNumber:*" + term + "*"
    Dim serverUrl As String = "https://api.federalreporter.nih.gov/"
    Dim requestUrl As String = "/v1/projects/search?query=" & termName & "&offset=" & CStr(offset) & "&limit=" & CStr(retLimit)
    Dim xmlOutputFormat As Boolean = False
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Try
        Using client = New System.Net.Http.HttpClient()
            client.BaseAddress = New Uri(serverUrl)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            If xmlOutputFormat Then
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"))
            Else
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
            End If
            Dim response As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(requestUrl)
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

            result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            Return result
        End Using
    Catch ex As System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
        'LogStatus(ex.Message.ToString)
        Throw
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

JavaScript function

```
    function search_project_number(projectNumber) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/biosketch.asmx/ADMIN_SearchGrantsJSON_projectNumber_Async",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                projectNumber: projectNumber
            }),
            beforeSend: function () { },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                build_table(data.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I need to call it with a JavaScript Function so it can parse the JSON object.  When I call it using the Javascipt I don't get anything.  No error and no Success.  When I call it with a desktop app I can see the JSON Object but still can't parse it out.  This is the first time I'm using a HttpClient and also the first time using a webservice call using Async.  I may be totally screwed up in both areas so I need a little help.  I've seen the word Promise - Is that what I'm missing?  Thanks for the help